# Ошибка NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity выдает ошибку

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   ActorController.CharacterMove () (at Assets/Scripts/Actor/ActorController.cs:43)
>   ActorController.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Actor/ActorController.cs:32).

указывающую на строку

```
moveVector.x = mContr.Horizontal() * speedMove;
```

класса `ActorController`.

Не понимаю сути ошибки.

```
public class ActorController : MonoBehaviour {

//Скорость ходьбы
public float speedMove;
//Сила прыжка
public float jumpPower;

//Направление движения персонажа
private Vector3 moveVector;

private CharacterController ch_controller;
private Animator ch_animator;
private ActorMobileController mContr;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    ch_controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    ch_animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    mContr = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Joystick").GetComponent<ActorMobileController>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    GamingGravity();
    CharacterMove();

}

//Метод перемещения персонажа
private void CharacterMove()
{

    if (ch_controller.isGrounded)
    {
        moveVector = Vector3.zero;
        moveVector.x = mContr.Horizontal() * speedMove;
        moveVector.z = mContr.Vertical() * speedMove;
    }

    if (moveVector.x != 0 || moveVector.z != 0) ch_animator.SetBool("Move", true);
    else ch_animator.SetBool("Move", false);

    if (Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, moveVector) > 1f || Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, moveVector) == 0)
    {

        Vector3 direct = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, moveVector, speedMove, 0.0f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direct);

    }

    moveVector.y = gravityForce;

    ch_controller.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
}
}


public class ActorMobileController : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler {

private Image joystickBG;
[SerializeField]
private Image joystick;
private Vector2 inputVector;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    joystickBG = GetComponent<Image>();
    joystick = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();

}

public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
{

    OnDrag(ped);

}

public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
{

    inputVector = Vector2.zero;
    joystick.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;

}

public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped)
{

    Vector2 pos;
    if(RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(joystickBG.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos))
    {

        pos.x = (pos.x / joystickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
        pos.y = (pos.y / joystickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);

        inputVector = new Vector2(pos.x * 2 - 1, pos.y * 2 - 1);
        inputVector = (inputVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;

        joystick.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(inputVector.x * (joystickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 2), inputVector.y * (joystickBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 2));

    }
}

public float Horizontal()
{

    if (inputVector.x != 0) return inputVector.x;
    else return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

}

public float Vertical()
{

    if (inputVector.y != 0) return inputVector.y;
    else return Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть ошибки NullReferenceException - вы пытаетесь что-то сделать со ссылочной переменной, которая имеет значение null. т.е. mContr на момент вашего обращения к ней ничего не назначено и эта переменная указывает в пустоту. Как следствие вызов метода у пустоты выдаёт ошибку.

А раз там пусто, значит нижеприведённая строчка кода ничего не находит. Не стоит делать такие длинные цепочки вызовов, когда вы не уверены, что всё и везде назначено. Как вариант, хотя бы, ставьте проверку, чтобы знать сразу, что всё плохо. Например, так:

```
mContr = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Joystick").GetComponent<ActorMobileController>();
Debug.Assert(mContr, "Not found ActorMobileController!", this);
```